# Handle Laravel 404 or 500 error in jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm currently stuck on an issue where I'm unable to handle `404` or `500` error with jQuery AJAX. I'm fetching some data from controller, and I'm returning `json()` with relevant status code:

```
public function getFilteredProducts(Request $request){
    $products = Product::where('product_category_id', $request->category_id)->get();
    if(count($products)){
        return response()->json([
            'products' => $products,
            'category_id' => $request->category_id,
        ], 200);
    }else{
        return response()->json([
            'product_category_id' => $request->category_id
        ], 404);
    }
}
```

This is my AJAX function:

```
$.ajax({
            url: `/shop/filtered-products/${category_id}`,
            type: 'get',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.csrfToken
            },
            success: function (data) {
                //Do something on succes
            },
            statusCode: {
                404: function (data) {
                    //Hande 404 code
                },
                500: function (data) {
                    //Handle 505 code
                }
            }
});
```

This works perfectly when there are products found & when I return `200` status. But the problem occurs when I return `404` status code & `statusCode` functions are not getting called. I can see the error in console, but the code is not executing:

[image]

I also tried to handle errors with `error` function, but no luck either:

```
$.ajax({
            url: `/shop/filtered-products/${category_id}`,
            type: 'get',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.csrfToken
            },
            success: function (data) {
                //Do something on succes
            },
            error: function (data) {
               //Handle any errors
            },
});
```

Expected result would be to execute some code on any of the following status codes(`404` or `500`). What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does explicitly indicating the `dataType: 'json'` makes a difference?

Answer (score 1):

In your controller just thrown an exception, which you can handle in the render function.

```
// IN YOUR CONTROLLER, CHANGE THE "else" STATEMENT LIKE THIS
if(count($products)) {
    return response()->json([
        'products' => $products,
        'category_id' => $request->get('category_id'),
    ], 200);
} else {
    throw new ModelNotFoundException($request->get('category_id'));
}
```

Don't forget to use this class above:

```
// DON'T FORGET TO USE THIS
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
```

In "app/Exceptions/Handler.php" add the code-block before existing line (by default).

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    // ADD THIS BLOCK IN "app/Exceptions/Handler"
    $product_id = (int)($exception->getMessage());
    if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        return response()->json([
            'product_category_id' => $product_id,
        ], 404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

That's it. But remember, this is just one of many solutions. Actually you can create your custom exceptions and thrown them. For more you can see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#renderable-exceptions)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this:

```
$.ajax({     
  headers: {
    //...        
    Accept: "application/json",         
  },
  //...
});
```

Handled for you by Laravel [expectsJson()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithContentTypes.php#L24) in [render()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L306) method

Comment: What you did is already handled by Laravel. You should only do this if you want to change its behavior. Have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by using different parameters in AJAX error function, something like this:

```
        statusCode: {
            404: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                //Handle 404 error
            },
            500: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                //Handle 500 error
            }
        }
```

When I added LHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown parameters, my error was getting caught in AJAX as expected. To return errors, I used this in controllers to return exceptions:

```
return response()->json([
                'error' => 'Kategorija nema proizvoda',
                'product_category_id' => $request->category_id
            ], 404);
```